# What does “int 0x2A” mean in assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, x86-16, instructions

Does anyone know what the instruction `INT 0x2A` does in assembly x86?

I have used it and it just loads some random values in registers **EAX,ECX,EDX**

What does this instruction with that code does?

I have looked on [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-2a.htm)

but it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)

Comment: doesn't make sense how?  What did you set `ah` or `ax` to before running `int 0x2a`?  That documentation you linked looks perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: That link you included makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x86 interrupt here you are talking about is DOS interrupt and not part of BIOS IVT, it is in fact part of DOS API,

Most calls to the DOS API are invoked using software interrupt 21h (INT 21h). By calling INT 21h with a subfunction number in the AH processor register and other parameters in other registers, one invokes various DOS services. DOS services include keyboard input, video output, disk file access, executing programs, memory allocation, and various other things.

Interrupt vector 2Ah:

Networking and critical section,Called by DOS kernel to interface with networking software. It also has many different functions for different purposes.

You can visit Ralf Brown's list for more functional details on this interrupt: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-2a.htm

Comment: Yes i have noticed that. Some are preserved for the BIOS. as i seen here http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_table.html. I actually just found a simple app that used this INT 2A so i was wondering what it does. Here is that simple app https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/corkami/int2a_loop.exe.

Comment: You can visit Ralf brown interrupt list, to see all interrupts in BIOS IVT.